# Installing mysql-libs on server with MySQL-Server5.5

Tags: mysql, centos, review-board

I'm trying to install ReviewBoard on my server, but I keep on getting the following errors.

```
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.32-1.cp1136.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.32-1.cp1136.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.32-1.cp1136.x86_64
```

The OS is Centos 6. Could anyone please explain to me what I should do to fix this issue? I have read that I should uninstall the MySQL server first, but I have numerous websites running from it, so it is a no go. What do you suggest I do? Is there a way I can bypass this?

Kind Regards,
EZFrag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, this is a common problem with MySQL packages within CentOS 6. Yum is trying to satisfy requirements by installing `mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64`. This package conflicts with files from package `MySQL55-server-5.5.32-1.cp1136.x86_64`.

There is a way to fix this without breaking your rpm database or uninstalling mysql55, just download mysql compatibility libs from mysql for el6 (CentOS and RHEL6 are full binary compatible). Get `MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-2.el6.x86_64.rpm` (just google for it) and install this rpm using: `rpm -ihv MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-2.el6.x86_64.rpm`.

After this you can install ReviewBoard without yum trying to install mysql51 libs for satisfying dependencies.

Here is the link to the official package provided by MySQL: [MySQL shared compat](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-2.el6.x86_64.rpm/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/)

Comment: Here is the [link to the official MySQL package](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-2.el6.x86_64.rpm/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/) (just so that you don't end up with downloading packages from dubious sources)

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I was not sure if I should provide a link to the official MySQL package since it will be gone with next release of MySQL. I will additionaly add it to my answer.

Comment: Well... that was quite the yum intro for me. Thanks, it worked 150% :)

Comment: This error persists even after installing shared-compat rpm. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue at mysql upgrade to 5.5-remi, but it caused by old yum cache.