# install phpmyadmin with mysql 5.6.13 CentOS 6.4 64bit

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I installed CentOS 6.4 x86_64 and then install on it web server and mysql 5.6.13

MySQL-server-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

MySQL-client-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

MySQL-shared-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

MySQL-devel-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

and I want to install phpmyadmin

I used `yum install phpmyadmin` but not working

```
================================================================================
 Package               Arch         Version                 Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 phpMyAdmin            noarch       3.5.8.1-1.el6           epel          4.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libXpm                x86_64       3.5.10-2.el6            base           51 k
 libmcrypt             x86_64       2.5.8-9.el6             epel           96 k
 mysql-libs            x86_64       5.1.69-1.el6_4          updates       1.2 M
 php-gd                x86_64       5.3.3-23.el6_4          updates       106 k
 php-mbstring          x86_64       5.3.3-23.el6_4          updates       455 k
 php-mcrypt            x86_64       5.3.3-1.el6             epel           18 k
 php-mysql             x86_64       5.3.3-23.el6_4          updates        81 k
 php-pdo               x86_64       5.3.3-23.el6_4          updates        75 k
 php-php-gettext       noarch       1.0.11-3.el6            epel           21 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install      10 Package(s)

Total size: 6.4 M
Installed size: 25 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y

Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 conflicts 
Error Summary
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17658509/1928023) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.13-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` and it will work.