# mysql 5.5 on centos 6.4

Tags: mysql, linux, centos6

I have a requirement for MySQL 5.5, and the box is a CentOS 6.4 64-bit VM.

MySQL 5.1.69 is installed, and won't let me install any of the RPMs from the 5.5 RPMs..

- MySQL-client-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-devel-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-embedded-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-server-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-shared-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- MySQL-test-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

So I run yum -y remove mysql and then try to install the newer version.   I first of all run

- rpm -ivh  MySQL-shared-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
- rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

So far so good.  I then try to install the server.

rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

And I get this..

file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64

... and so on.  If I google some of those errors, I get this page from StackOverflow..

[Installing mysql-libs on server with MySQL-Server5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531173/installing-mysql-libs-on-server-with-mysql-server5-5)

.. but if I look at the advice, it says to install the MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.32-2.el6.x86_64.rpm.  But it's already installed.  :(

Any advice would be welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17658509/1928023) answer to almost duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

One way is to install all the RPMs at the same time with `yum install MySQL*.rpm`, which ideally should take care of all package dependencies and upgrades.

You can also get around this problem by using the `--replacefiles` option to RPM:

```
rpm -ivh --replacefiles MySQL-server-5.5.32-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

That uses the error message language files from the server package to overwrite those in the 5.1 version that comes with CentOS.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Mark it is as the correct answer so future visitors can benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with webtatic repository. 
Using remi, epel and rpmforge repository saved me the trouble.

Here is the link I referred : 
[Cent OS 6.4, Php 5.4, Mysql 5.5 - HowTo](http://webees.me/how-to-install-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-in-centos-6-4-via-yum/)